# Javascript unable to get JSON data from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm having a bit of a problem reading JSON data that I generate in PHP and then pass back to my Javascript and I'm not sure why.

Here is the PHP:

```
header("content-type: text/json");

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
// echo the result as a JSON object
echo json_encode($result);
```

And here is the Javscript:

```
$.post("payment_do.php", { "token": response.response.token, "ip_address": response.ip_address}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

It seems as though if I take the header line away in the PHP I get a response that I can read in the Javascript but I cannot access any of the elements the way you would expect. If I leave the header in there, I get no response readable by the javascript.

EDIT: Now getting a response from the php, looks like this:

```
"{\"response\":{\"token\":\"ch_9knTXHoU0dVZsl7iMHyHGg\",\"success\":true,\"amount\":9900,\"currency\":\"AUD\",\"description\":\"test\",\"email\":\"test@test.com\",\"ip_address\":\"1.1.1.1\",\"created_at\":\"2013-03-18T23:49:12Z\",\"status_message\":\"Success!\",\"error_message\":null,\"card\":{\"token\":\"test_token\",\"display_number\":\"XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-0000\",\"scheme\":\"master\",\"address_line1\":\"123 Fake Street Fakington\",\"address_line2\":null,\"address_city\":\"moon\",\"address_postcode\":\"2121\",\"address_state\":\"NSW\",\"address_country\":\"Australia\"},\"transfer\":[],\"amount_refunded\":0,\"total_fees\":999,\"merchant_entitlement\":999,\"refund_pending\":false}}"
```

In the end I had to remove the json_encode function in the php and just return the result. In the javascript (using jQuery) I then called:

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

With which I could then access the elements of the object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your header to `application/json` (as opposed to `text/json`). In addition, if you actually want to further process the results of the `curl_exec` call then you need to set an additional option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

This will cause the `curl_exec` call to return data on success, as opposed to TRUE.

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if(! $result) {
    // handle error
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Also, you will want to verify the data you are getting back from the cURL call - make sure that it really needs to be encoded before being returned.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this. I still get the error where I can't see the JSON. I just get no response in the javascript, as soon as I comment this line out. I can see the JSON response but can't access any of the elements.

Comment: So, you see the JSON data come back as a response, in the console, but you can't use it? Is that a fair statement?

Comment: Yes - exactly. It seems that cURL is returning the data without me explicitly telling it to. The `$result` variable just `true` which is encoded as `1` by the `json_encode`.

Comment: @rheotron - good additional info. I've edited my answer to reflect some additional things you probably need to implement.

Comment: Yeah - that's working now. I can get the correct data back from the cURL. The only problem I'm having now is that cURL seems to put in a whole lot of slashes and it seems to be returned to the Javascript as a string even with the `json_encode`. Any ideas?

Comment: Can't really say without seeing the data. Log the result from the `curl_exec` call and add a portion of it to your question.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to see the results from the curl_exec call, as opposed to the data that the client is getting. However, I think that your json_encode call is unnecessary. You should be able to just `echo $result` and be ok.

Answer (score 2):

add this:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($result);
```